# WinXP: Is NTFS appropriate for SSDs?

Tags: windows-xp, ssd, filesystems, ntfs, fat32

I've just bought an SSD (SLC 32GB PATA) for my old laptop and now I have to decide which file system to use for each partition.
I'm goint to need two partitions: one for the OS installation and the other for storing my personal files.
Now, if I remember well, you can install Windows XP only on a NTFS partition, so there is no choice there.
But for the other partition I could choose between NTFS and FAT32.

What file system do you recommend in this case?
Do you have any experience on using FAT32 on a SSD? Is it better (faster) than NTFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disadvantages of FAT32

1. No journaling, data loss will result during a hard crash
2. 4gb file size limit

This should be enough reason to go with NTFS

Comment: NTFS is also more efficent with the space it is given, a 20GB partition formatted with FAT32 will hold less data than a 20GB partition with NTFS.

Comment: So much truth in these posts.